# How to add Text to left and right in the title page

Tags: graphics, text

I am trying to add two persons' names and details on a report's title page.

I am very new to latex and have been trying to use flushleft and flustright But the expected format is not working.

I also need to add an image **Only below the left supervisor's name** (refer to the image). Any Leads would be really helpful. Thank you in Advance

The code I am working on right now is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, BCOR1cm,toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{titlepage}

{
    \begin{center}
        \raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{Image.pdf}}\\
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}

\begin{center}
\LARGE{\textbf{Title of the Report}}\\
\vspace{1cm}


\Large{\textbf{My Report}}\\ 
\vspace{1cm}
Submitted in Fulfilment of the\\
Requirements for the Academic Degree\\
Text.\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Dept. of XXXX XXXX\\
Chair of XXXXX XXXXXX
\end{center}
\vspace{3cm}
Submitted by: Name\\
Student ID: 111222\\
Date: 12.12.1212\\
\vspace{0.3cm}\\

%this is the place I want to add the left and right texts with an image
Supervising tutor: XXXX  \\


\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I found some questions on adding names on the title page for left and right side but I am  unable to implement it with an image

[image: Example Foramt]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I have updated the question with a working example. and added a comment line where I wanted add the code

Comment: But your code still does not start with`\documentclass{...}` or ends with `\end{document}` ... Also, don't use `\\` where they are not needed.

Comment: @JasperHabicht - I added the document class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TEX!

Please see if this satisfies the requirement - do try and give a minimum working example(MWE), as explained on the website(try the search),  to work on -otherwise it is all guess work and assumptions

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushleft\small
Supervising Tutor: First Name LName\\
University Name
    \end{minipage}%
\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushright\small
External Supervisor: First Name LName\\
University Name: XXX
    \end{minipage}%
%

\bigskip

\noindent
%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushleft\small
    \phantom{Supervising Tutor: First Name LName}\\
    \phantom{University Name}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}
\end{minipage}%
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried using flushright to push the figure to extreme right (below the External Supervisor text) but the image is not moving.